# What can cause charge density wave (CDW) in 3D metal except for fermi surface nesting?

Tags: condensed-matter

As we know, the charge density wave (CDW) naturally happens in 1D metal at low temperature due to Peierls instability. It also happens when you have fermi surface nesting in 2D or quasi 2D metal. But what's else, should there be any more mechanism to cause CDW or that's just all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CDW in Chromium whose origin is still not completely understood.  It may be driven by a spin-density-wave for which there is some nesting. See https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-022-28104-2